# List of Figures / Tables Prefixed with "Figures" or "Tables"

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables)

I'm attempting to modify the figure and table listing in my document from:

```
3.1 Some_Figure
```

To:

```
Figure 3.1 Some_Figure
```

I'd like to also have the same behavior for the table listing.

```
3.1 Some_Table
```

To:

```
Table 3.1 Some_Table
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using `titletoc` or perhaps something I'm not aware of?

Comment: If you don't mind using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) (as opposed to [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)), the following would solve your problem: [List of Figures - how to add caption label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12865/5764); and then there's also [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20337/5764) that uses the same approach. Let us know if you want a `titletoc`-specific solution.

Comment: Thanks Werner, worked like a charm. The only reason I suggested titletoc was because I know it has the capability to perform such actions, but I have no specific requirement to have it done in titletoc. Thanks again for all of your help! Feel free to comment this so that I can select your answer as the selected one to help you out too.

Comment: To avoid duplication, we'll probably close this question, which will point future users to the respective posts.