# "Table"/"Figure" in items of List of tables/figures

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables)

Hello guys the list of figures and tables in my thesis is listed as (I use `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`)

```
Table

1.2 Name1
```

But I want it to be like

```
Table 

Table 1.2 Name1
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution uses the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package.The way that your list of tables and list of figures appear are defined by the commands `\cftfigfont` and `\cfttabfont`. Write the following code in your preamble.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }
```

Comment: Thnx I tried that after u told me and here is the error message...



\newcounter{lofdepth}


   \setcounter{lofdepth}{1}




do u need to edit something else?

Comment: The problem is that both packages define the counters lofdepth and lotdepth. To prevent the error, simply load tocloft with the subfigure option; i.e., load the packages like this:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}

this worked ...thnx

Comment: This did not work for me. It made the page titles very large, but did not add "Figure" or "Table" before each number as I wanted.