# Adding a dash between words in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

Yesteday I was Searching in this site some help to construct my dissertation, my trouble was modify the style of the list of figures in LaTeX, more specificaly, add the word "Figure 1" before each entry in list of figures, then this answer helpS, look:
 [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables/)

But, moreover I need iserting a little dash between the word figure and the entry of the list. I need something like this:

Figure 1 - Entry of the list

For now, I don't have that little dash, someone can help with this, I'd be thankful!

I have this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}  
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure\ }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table\ }

\newlength{\mylenf}
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+1.5em}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\listoftablesandfigures{%
    \chapter*{List of Tables and Figures}%
    \phantomsection
\@starttoc{lof}%
\bigskip
\@starttoc{lot}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftablesandfigures

\chapter{Test one}
\section{Test one one}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Test table one}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test figure one}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test two}
\section{Test two two}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Test table two}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test figure two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is this

[image]

How can I add a little dash between the words "Figure 1" and "Test of figure one"?

Comment: A lot of this depends on the document class you are using. Could you please provide a minimal example showing what you have now?

Comment: @daleif, Sure! Wait a moment please.

Comment: @daleif I'm sorry, but I'm new here, I don't know how insert the latex code.

Comment: It was edited! Some answer? Thanks!

Comment: One question: How about the number of figs. If the number is more than 10, `Figure 10` takes up more space than `Figure 1`, where should the alignment be?

Comment: @daleif In my case, I have only two figures, so I think this will not be a problem, do you have some idea?

Comment: See my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick

```
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2em}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
```

Since `Table` is shorter than `Figure` is does not quite line up. The main problem here is that the material (the number and the title) is handed over to the typesetting macro as a single construction. Similar to

```
\numberline{number}Title
```

Where the `\numberline` is giving the box of a certain width.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot, you really save my work!

Answer (score 1):

Add something like

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ -- }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ -- }
```

in the preamble. So you get
[image]

Comment: It works too, thanks for colaborate with the answer!