# How to use ERT command to long tables that is provided for float table

Tags: tables, lyx, captions, longtable

I have been provided with ERT (Evil Red Text) command which when used for float tables, displays the caption of the table as Table 1.1 in List of Tables.
I want to know how I can use such command for `longtable`s. For example, I want to

1. Create a float `table`;
2. Add ERT command `\isucaption{blah blah....}`;
3. View the table in List of Tables.

Result the table entry in List of Tables (LoT) is shown as `Table 1.1 blah blah`

But if I don't use an ERT command then table entry in LoT is `1.1 blah blah`. That is, the word `Table` is missing.

I want to use this command for long tables that are not floats so that the entries in lot for such tables will also contain `Table` word, But I am not sure where I can add ERT for `longtable`s?

Answer (score 1):

[`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) was written in a way to emulate a regular `table` environment, just without the floating capability, but supplementing that loss with the (great) ability to break across the page. So you don't have to do anything special for a `longtable`'s `\caption` to end up in the List of Tables (LoT). That leaves only the insertion of `Table` in front of the LoT entries. For this, I used [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20337/5764) as reference.

In your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, add

```
\usepackage{longtable,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table~}    
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{5em}
```

Note that mixing regular floating `table` environments with some `longtable`s might cause problems with the ordering of LoT content. With enough content between a `table` and a `longtable` might solve such problems, but this depends heavily on your document structure.